# Can't move the ball with directional keys in turtle-graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i am supposed to code an escape game for a project and i cant move the character. Here is my code, excuse me if it doesn't look good, i am new to this.

```
import turtle


def lire_matrice(fichier):
    with open(fichier) as firstf:
        lecteur = firstf.read()
        list_base = lecteur.split('\n')
        matrice = []
        for i in list_base:
            list_dans_matrice = (i.split())
            matrice.append(list_dans_matrice)
        return matrice

def calculer_pas(matrice):
    pas1 = (440//len(matrice))
    pas2 = (330//len(matrice[0]))
    if pas1 > pas2:
        pas = pas2
    else:
        pas = pas1
    return pas


def coordonne_case(case, pas):
    case_0 = (-240, 200)
    x = case_0[0] + case[1] * pas
    y = case_0[1] - case[0] * pas
    coordonne = (x, y)
    return coordonne

def coordonne_balle(case, pas):
    case_0 = (-240 + pas/2, 200 - pas/2)
    x = case_0[0] + case[1] * pas
    y = case_0[1] - case[0] * pas
    coordonne = (x, y)
    return coordonne


def tracer_carre(dimension):
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(dimension)
        turtle.rt(90)


def tracer_case(case,couleur, pas):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(case[0], case[1])
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color(couleur)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    tracer_carre(pas)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()


def afficher_plan(matrice, pas):
    for ligne in range(len(matrice)):
        for index in range(len(matrice[ligne])):
            if matrice[ligne][index] == '0':
                tracer_case(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas), 'white', pas)
                liste_all.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))

            elif matrice[ligne][index] == '1':
                tracer_case(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas), 'grey', pas)
                liste_mur.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))
                liste_all.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))

            elif matrice[ligne][index] == '2':
                tracer_case(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas), 'yellow', pas)
                liste_fin.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))
                liste_all.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))

            elif matrice[ligne][index] == '3':
                tracer_case(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas), 'orange', pas)
                liste_porte.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))
                liste_all.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))

            elif matrice[ligne][index] == '4':
                tracer_case(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas), 'green', pas)
                liste_objet.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))
                liste_all.append(coordonne_case((ligne, index), pas))

    return liste_porte, liste_fin, liste_objet, liste_mur, liste_all

"""Deplacement"""


def deplacer_gauche():
    global position
    mouve = position[0], position[1] - 1
    return mouve


def deplacer_droite():
    global position
    mouve = position[0], position[1] + 1
    return mouve


def deplacer_bas():
    global position
    mouve = position[0] + 1, position[1]
    return mouve


def deplacer_haut():
    global position
    mouve = position[0] - 1, position[1]
    return mouve
def deplacement(mouvement, turtle_used, pas):
    turtle_used.clear()
    turtle_used.goto(coordonne_balle(mouvement, pas))
    turtle_used.pendown()
    turtle_used.begin_fill()
    turtle_used.dot(10)
    turtle_used.end_fill()
    turtle_used.penup()


""" Variables
"""
position = 0, 1
liste_mur = []
liste_porte = []
liste_objet = []
liste_fin = []
liste_all = []
lp = liste_porte
lf = liste_fin
lo = liste_objet
lm = liste_mur
lall = liste_all
d_fin = {'fin': lf}
d_porte = {'porte': lp}
d_objet = {'objet': lo}
d_mur = {'mur': lm}
d_all = {'all': lall}
matrice = lire_matrice('plan_chateau.txt')
pas = calculer_pas(matrice)

""" Main code
"""
"""carte"""
turtle.tracer(0, 0)
afficher_plan(matrice, pas)
"""Deplacement"""
balle = turtle.Turtle()
balle.fillcolor('red')
balle.penup()
balle.goto(coordonne_balle((0, 1),pas))
balle.pendown()
balle.dot(10)
balle.end_fill()

turtle.listen()    # Déclenche l’écoute du clavier
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_gauche, "Left")   # Associe à la touche Left une fonction appelée deplacer_gauche
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_droite, "Right")
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_haut, "Up")
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_bas, "Down")
turtle.mainloop()
mouvement_gauche = deplacer_gauche()
mouvement_droite = deplacer_droite()
mouvement_bas = deplacer_bas()
mouvement_haut = deplacer_haut()
while True:
    if position != mouvement_haut:
        deplacement(mouvement_haut, balle, pas)
        position = mouvement_haut
    elif position != mouvement_bas:
        deplacement(mouvement_bas, balle, pas)
        position = mouvement_bas
    elif position != mouvement_droite:
        deplacement(mouvement_droite, balle, pas)
        position = mouvement_droite
    elif position != mouvement_gauche:
        deplacement(mouvement_gauche, balle, pas)
        position = mouvement_gauche
```

the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File , line 172, in <module>
    deplacement(mouvement_haut, balle, pas)
  File , line 112, in deplacement
    turtle_used.clear()
  File , line 2643, in clear
    self._clear()
  File , line 2621, in _clear
    self.screen._delete(item)
  File , line 558, in _delete
    self.cv.delete(item)
  File "<string>", line 1, in delete
  File  line 2820, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, I don't believe that there is an efficient way to use the arrow keys to move a sprite/object.

If you know how to set the keys, I would recommend using w,a,s, and d to move it. If using the arrow keys is some sort of requirement for a class or something, I would either wait for a more advanced python programmer to answer or just look it up online.

Comment: From turtle's perspective, arrow keys are just the same as any other key.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how turtle key events work, and invoking them incorrectly.  First, nothing should follow `mainloop()` as it turns control over to the tkinter event handler, and any code that follows it won't get executed until the entire turtle world is torn down.

Second, event handlers don't return *anything*.  They can *do* things, but they don't *return* results.

Since your "plan_chateau.txt" file isn't included, and there isn't much description as to what your code does, below is my best guess as to how your program should operate, including changes not mentioned above:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def read_matrix(filename):
    matrix = []

    with open(filename) as file:
        player = file.read()
        list_base = player.split('\n')

        for i in list_base:
            list_in_matrix = i.split()
            matrix.append(list_in_matrix)

    return matrix

def calculate_scale(matrix):
    scale1 = 440 // len(matrix)
    scale2 = 330 // len(matrix[0])

    return scale2 if scale1 > scale2 else scale1

def coordinates_box(box, scale):
    box_0 = (-240, 200)
    x = box_0[0] + box[1] * scale
    y = box_0[1] - box[0] * scale

    return (x, y)

def coordinates_ball(box, scale):
    box_0 = (-240 + scale/2, 200 - scale/2)
    x = box_0[0] + box[1] * scale
    y = box_0[1] - box[0] * scale

    return (x, y)

def draw_square(dimension):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(dimension)
        turtle.right(90)

def draw_box(box, color, scale):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(box)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    draw_square(scale)
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

def view_plan(matrix, scale):
    for line in range(len(matrix)):
        for index in range(len(matrix[line])):
            if matrix[line][index] == '0':
                draw_box(coordinates_box((line, index), scale), 'white', scale)
                all_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
            elif matrix[line][index] == '1':
                draw_box(coordinates_box((line, index), scale), 'grey', scale)
                wall_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
                all_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
            elif matrix[line][index] == '2':
                draw_box(coordinates_box((line, index), scale), 'yellow', scale)
                exit_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
                all_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
            elif matrix[line][index] == '3':
                draw_box(coordinates_box((line, index), scale), 'orange', scale)
                door_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
                all_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
            elif matrix[line][index] == '4':
                draw_box(coordinates_box((line, index), scale), 'green', scale)
                object_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))
                all_list.append(coordinates_box((line, index), scale))

### Displacement

position = [0, 1]

def move_left():
    global position

    movement_left = position[0], position[1] - 1
    displacement(movement_left, ball, scale)
    position = movement_left

def move_right():
    global position

    movement_right = position[0], position[1] + 1
    displacement(movement_right, ball, scale)
    position = movement_right

def move_down():
    global position

    movement_down = position[0] + 1, position[1]
    displacement(movement_down, ball, scale)
    position = movement_down

def move_up():
    global position

    movement_up = position[0] - 1, position[1]
    displacement(movement_up, ball, scale)
    position = movement_up

def displacement(movement, turtle_used, scale):
    turtle_used.goto(coordinates_ball(movement, scale))

### Variables

wall_list = []
door_list = []
object_list = []
exit_list = []
all_list = []

matrix = read_matrix('plan_chateau.txt')
scale = calculate_scale(matrix)

### Main code

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

# map
view_plan(matrix, scale)

# Displacement
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('circle')
ball.shapesize(10 / CURSOR_SIZE)
ball.fillcolor('red')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(coordinates_ball((0, 1), scale))

# Associe à la touche Left une fonction appelée move_left
screen.onkeypress(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(move_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(move_down, 'Down')
screen.listen()  # Déclenche l’écoute du clavier

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue lies here:

```
def deplacer_gauche():
    global position
    mouve = position[0], position[1] - 1
    return mouve


def deplacer_droite():
    global position
    mouve = position[0], position[1] + 1
    return mouve


def deplacer_bas():
    global position
    mouve = position[0] + 1, position[1]
    return mouve


def deplacer_haut():
    global position
    mouve = position[0] - 1, position[1]
    return mouve
```

and here:

```
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_gauche, "Left")
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_droite, "Right")
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_haut, "Up")
turtle.onkeypress(deplacer_bas, "Down")
```

Your functions each return a value, but when you call the functions in `turtle.onkeypress`, the values don't get assigned to any variable, hence the functions won't do anything.

Try something like

```
def deplacer_gauche():
    gballe.setx(balle.xcor() - 1)


def deplacer_droite():
    gballe.setx(balle.xcor() + 1)


def deplacer_bas():
    gballe.setx(balle.ycor() - 1)


def deplacer_haut():
    gballe.setx(balle.ycor() + 1)
```